# Asynchronous initialization and its unit testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, initialization

**Background**
I need some class to perform background initialization, which should start in constructor. Currently I'm using a `Task` which is started by constructor, and then all operations, depending on that initialization wait for that `Task` completion.

Please take a look at the following simplified example:

```
interface IEntry {}

interface IRepository
{
    IQueryable<IEntry> Query { get; }
    void Add(IEntry entry);
}

class PrefetchedRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly Task _prefetchingTask;
    private readonly ICollection<IEntry> _entries = new List<IEntry>();
    private readonly IRepository _underlyingRepository;

    public PrefetchedRepository(IRepository underlyingRepository)
    {
        _underlyingRepository = underlyingRepository;
        // Background initialization starts here
        _prefetchingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Prefetch);
    }

    public IQueryable<IEntry> Query
    { 
        get
        {
            EnsurePrefetchCompleted();
            return _entries.AsQueryable();
        }
    }

    public void Add(IEntry entry)
    {
        EnsurePrefetchCompleted();      
        _entries.Add(entry);
        _underlyingRepository.Add(entry);
    }

    private void EnsurePrefetchCompleted()
    {
        _prefetchingTask.Wait();
    }

    private void Prefetch()
    {
        foreach (var entry in _underlyingRepository.Query)
        {
            _entries.Add(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

This works. The problem starts when I want to test initialization in Unit Test. I'm creating the instance and providing the mock of underlying repository. I want to ensure that all entries were fetched from the mock as expected.

```
[TestFixture]
public class PrefetchingRepositoryTests
{
    [Test]
    public void WhenInitialized_PrefetchingIsDone()
    {
        // Arrange
        var underlyingRepositoryMock = A.Fake<IRepository>();

        // Act
        var target = new PrefetchedRepository(_underlyingRepository);

        // Assert
        underlyingRepositoryMock.CallsTo(r => r.Query).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly(1));   
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, most of the time fails, because actually initialization didn't started yet at the assertion point.

**Questions**

*Question 1 - **Initialization**:* Is there more elegant way of asynchronous initialization rather than starting task in constructor and waiting for it in all dependent operations?

*Question 2 - **Testing**:* I thought of 2 possible ways to solve race between the test and testee:

1. Using event handle to the test:

   ```
   [Test]
   public void WhenInitialized_PrefetchingIsDone()
   {
       // Arrange ...
       var invokedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
       underlyingRepositoryMock.CallsTo(r => r.Query).Invokes(_ => invokedEvent.Set());

       // Act ...

       // Assert
       Assert.True(invokedEvent.WaitOne(1000));
   }
   ```
2. Exposing `EnsurePrefetchCompleted` method as internal and using it in the Unit Test (assuming usage of `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("...")]`)

The problem with both solutions is that in case of failure time duration long (actually in the second case - it is limited by test timeout).

Is there any simpler way to do this kind of testing?

Comment: Just to add that if this was some legacy code, i'd just use reflection to call that private EnsurePrefetchCompleted() method.

Comment: Regarding your first question, I describe [a number of approaches on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the prefetch logic into a separate Prefetcher class and when testing mock the Prefetcher with something that does the fetching without the use of a separate thread.

This will allow you to do the white-box testing of your PrefetchedRepository which I see you are attempting to do with 
 `underlyingRepositoryMock.CallsTo(r => r.Query).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly(1));`  (I would never do white-box testing, but that's just me.)

Once you are done with your white box testing, you can then do black-box testing of your PrefetchedRepository, without concern as to how it works internally.  (Whether it invokes other objects to do its job, how many times it invokes them, etc.)  Therefore, your testing code will not need to guess the point in time when it is okay to check whether query has been invoked, because it will not be concerned at all with whether query was invoked or not.  Essentially, your testing code will be testing against `interface IRepository`, not against `class PrefetchedRepository`.

Comment: This definitely will solve the problem with repository testing. But how should I test in this case the real asynchronous Prefetcher?

Comment: I amended my answer; please let me know if it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expose a instance which is in invalid state. Client code may often notice a delay when calling any members in `PrefetchedRepository` just because the underlying repository is slow. You're trying to be clever by hiding these details by hiding all the grotty waiting logic inside `EnsurePrefetchCompleted` which client code doesn't even know. But this may surprise the client why does even this takes a lot of time??

Better approach is to expose the `Task` in the public surface of the API and let the client code `await` it before it does anything with the repository instance.

Something like this:

```
class PrefetchedRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly Task _prefetchingTask;
    private readonly ICollection<IEntry> _entries = new List<IEntry>();
    private readonly IRepository _underlyingRepository;

    public PrefetchedRepository(IRepository underlyingRepository)
    {
        _underlyingRepository = underlyingRepository;
        // Background initialization starts here
        _prefetchingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Prefetch);
    }

    public Task Initialization
    { 
        get
        {
            return _prefetchingTask;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you could do

```
var repo = new PrefetchedRepository(someOtherSlowRepo);
await repo.Initialization;
//Then do whatever with the repo.
```

Of course delete that `EnsurePrefetchCompleted` method and all calls to it.

But I do understand this introduces the smell so-called [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/).

Better design is to introduce a Factory which does this for you.

```
public class PrefetchedRepositoryFactory
{
    public Task<IRepository> CreateAsync()
    {
        //someOtherSlowRepo can be a parameter or instance field of this class
        var repo = new PrefetchedRepository(someOtherSlowRepo);
        await repo.Initialization;
        return repo;
    }
}
```

Then you could simply do

```
var repo = await prefetchedRepositoryFactory.CreateAsync();
//Do whatever with repo.
```

If you do so, you don't have to take any special care for testing as you'll always have the fully constructed repository in hand.

You can await inside the Test methods; Most of the major unittesting frameworks supports `async Task` returning methods.

Comment: Nice solution, but it involves changing the way I receive instance of repository. I would prefer not to change this, but to limit the changes in the scope of the implementation. As for slowness and other considerations - `PrefetchingRepository` was just an example of some background initialization, which I need to start in constructor. My real problem is rather far from data fetching